# How to figure out why executable crashes (I don't have the source code)

Tags: debugging, apple

I'm trying to install PowerPanel Business Edition on Apple OS X.13. The server starts and exits (quits) - no log file, no error message. It works fine on my other OS Apple machines but on this High Sierra mac it won't run. The vendor is saying that there must be a conflict with another software and that it uses ports: 3052 (UDP/TCP), 53568 (TCP), 161 (UDP), 162 (UDP), 53566 (UDP), but I do not see those ports being used using this command:

```
$ lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to check ports, and if no, is there any way (given that I don't have access to the source) to get a clue as to what this executable is doing when it crashes?

Comment: Would an strace (or OS X.13 equivalent) help?

Comment: crashes may be written to some `Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter` directory with more information on what went awry. otherwise you could run it under `dtruss` or otherwise trace it with `dtrace` to see how its system calls differ from where it launches without error

Comment: Look at the dup. If a port is in use, it's likely running as a user other than your userid. Try using `sudo lsof...` as in the examples in the dup.